# Cals table import in indesign

Tags: macos

I have CALS table that i need to import in InDesign document. I have pasted the same below:

```
<table>
    <label>TABLE 1</label>
    <caption>
        <simple-para>Table title table title</simple-para>
    </caption>
    <tgroup cols="5">
        <colspec colname="col1" colnum="1" colwidth="96*"/>
        <colspec colname="col2" colnum="2" colwidth="98*"/>
        <colspec colname="col3" colnum="3" colwidth="95*"/>
        <colspec colname="col4" colnum="4" colwidth="103*"/>
        <colspec colname="col5" colnum="5" colwidth="103*"/>
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry nameend="col5" namest="col1">Table textTable textTable textTable textTable textTable textTable textTable textTable textTable textTable textTable textTable textTable text</entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <bold>abc</bold>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <bold>def</bold>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <bold>hig</bold>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <bold>klm</bold>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <bold>face</bold>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>tom</entry>
                <entry>Jerry</entry>
                <entry>fast</entry>
                <entry>running</entry>
                <entry>animals</entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>tom</entry>
                <entry>Jerry</entry>
                <entry>fast</entry>
                <entry>running</entry>
                <entry>animals</entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>tom</entry>
                <entry>Jerry</entry>
                <entry>fast</entry>
                <entry>running</entry>
                <entry>animals</entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>tom</entry>
                <entry>Jerry</entry>
                <entry>fast</entry>
                <entry>running</entry>
                <entry>animals</entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>tom</entry>
                <entry>Jerry</entry>
                <entry>fast</entry>
                <entry>running</entry>
                <entry>animals</entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

While importing the CALS table in indesign, I have to maintain the CALS table format in indesign too. I am not able to put the screen shot of indesign structure pallet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
     <label>TABLE 4-3</label>
     <caption id="cap0110">
         <simple-para id="sp0115">Estimated ME Requirements for Adult Psittacines in Various Environments and Activity Levels</simple-para>
     </caption>
     <table frame="none"><tgroup cols="2">
         <colspec colname="col1" colnum="1" colwidth="50%"/>
         <colspec colname="col2" colnum="2" colwidth="50%"/>
         <thead>
             <row>
                 <entry>Management Scenario</entry>
                 <entry>ME Requirement (kcal/day)</entry>
             </row>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <row>
                 <entry>Indoor cage</entry>
                 <entry>154.6 × (BW in kilograms)<sup>0.73</sup></entry>
             </row>
             <row>
                 <entry>Indoor aviary</entry>
                 <entry>176.6 × (BW in kilograms)<sup>0.73</sup></entry>
             </row>
             <row>
                 <entry>Outdoor aviary in warm/hot environment</entry>
                 <entry>203.9 × (BW in kilograms)<sup>0.73</sup></entry>
             </row>
             <row>
                 <entry>Outdoor aviary in cold environment</entry>
                 <entry>226.1 × (BW in kilograms)<sup>0.73</sup></entry>
             </row>
             <row>
                 <entry>Free ranging</entry>
                 <entry>229.2 × (BW in kilograms)<sup>0.73</sup></entry>
             </row>
         </tbody>
     </tgroup>
</table></table>
```

---

My XML file contains the above data, This is the code to import the XML file into the InDesign document...

This is working properly...

```
#target indesign
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var myFile = File.openDialog("Select XML file");
doc.importXML(myFile);
```